# String extraction: Understanding weird output

Tags: regex, r, substring, gsub

I have not used regular expressions much. I have been writing code to extract digits from Column names in R.

Column names:

```
c<- c("Variable182predict", "Variable123Target", "Timestamp", "TargetVariable")
```

I used the following function in R to extract digits:

```
numbers<-gsub(pattern=".*e(\\d+).*","\\1", c)
```

Luckily enough, I got digits but there are two outcomes which I am unable to understand in the output:

```
"182" "123" "Timestamp" "TargetVariable"
```

I got the rationale behind extracting digits, but why is it giving last two column names as it is. This is something which I am unable to understand. Any input will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Just gonna say that `c` is a really bad variable name

Comment: Definitely agree that `c` is not a suggested first choice for a variable name (though R is usually smart enough to handle it).

Comment: @hrbrmstr Ya but that 1 time it bites you in the ass is gonna be painful

Comment: It looks like it's just not changing the value of c because it's not matching in the first place.  Try using a regex that matches any string but only captures numbers followed by e:

`^.+?e(\d*).+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hrbrmstr and Jake Burkhead give you the explanation: what is not matched is not replaced.

Since the two last columns don't contain digits, they are not matched (and replaced).

A way to solve the problem is to replace all that is not a digit with nothing:

```
numbers<-gsub(pattern="\\D+","", c)
```

Comment: that. is. awesome. rly like the different approach and it's equally as easy to ignore the blank elements. #spiffy!

Answer (score 2):

`gsub()` is going to take the vector, look for the pattern, replace it where found and return each element whether it was replaced or not. You can use something like this:

```
library(stringr)

c.names <- c("Variable182predict", "Variable123Target", "Timestamp", "TargetVariable")
as.numeric(na.omit(str_extract(c.names, "\\d+")))
```

which will return

```
## [1] 182 123
```

(I made the assumption you only wanted the numeric output and nothing else)

The `stringr` is a pretty handy package to have around if you do alot with character vectors.

Comment: stringr doesnt work well with NAs and all encoding. But `stringi` does, so try this package :)

Answer (score 1):

From `?gsub`:

```
 Elements of character vectors ‘x’ which are not
 substituted will be returned unchanged
```

So if the regex doesn't match one of the input elements it does nothing to that element. The last 2 elements of your input vector don't match the pattern since they don't contain an e followed by one or more digits, so they are returned untouched.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all digits from text use this function from `stringi` package.
"Nd" is the class of decimal digits.

```
    stri_extract_all_charclass(c(123,43,"66ala123","kot"),"\\p{Nd}")
[[1]]
[1] "123"

[[2]]
[1] "43"

[[3]]
[1] "66"  "123"

[[4]]
[1] NA
```

Please note that here 66 and 123 numbers are extracted separatly and using gsub function they are paste together in 66123